# What is way to measure relationship between independent categorical variable on dependent variable (categorical/continuous)?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

If both dependent and independent are continuous then we can find correlation and we know which column can be more influential. But if independent variable is categorical, how will i know how much it is influencing dependent variable?